# Symfony 2.8 Could not load type "filter_text"

Tags: symfony

I'm starting on Symfony, I want to follow this how to (http://io.gchatelier.fr/blog/gestion-des-utilisateurs-groupes-et-roles-sous-symfony-2/).

The problem is after using the CRUD for users, when I go to check the result Symfony says:
Could not load type "filter_text"
I try the solution I found on https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/issues/201, change 'filter_text' by TextFilterType::class the problem change... the problem look to come from LexikFormFilterBundle

The problem look to come from this code:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('username', 'filter_text')
        ->add('usernameCanonical', 'filter_text')
        ->add('email', 'filter_text')
        ->add('emailCanonical', 'filter_text')
        ->add('enabled', 'filter_boolean')
        ->add('salt', 'filter_text')
        ->add('password', 'filter_text')
        ->add('lastLogin', 'filter_date')
        ->add('locked', 'filter_boolean')
        ->add('expired', 'filter_boolean')
        ->add('expiresAt', 'filter_date')
        ->add('confirmationToken', 'filter_text')
        ->add('passwordRequestedAt', 'filter_date')
        ->add('roles', 'filter_text')
        ->add('credentialsExpired', 'filter_boolean')
        ->add('credentialsExpireAt', 'filter_date')
        ->add('loginCount', 'filter_number')
        ->add('firstLogin', 'filter_date')
        ->add('group', 'filter_entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Group'))
    ;
}
```

Any idea ? Thank's

Totorux

Comment: What the next problem ? TextFilterType::class is the new way for create form type

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer, after the next error is: Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\Type\TextFilterType", I try to add "use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\LexikFormFilterBundle;" no change. Regards

Comment: I think you have a mistake in namespace  try set Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\TextFilterType::class in case for 'filter_text'

Comment: Thank's this part look to work now.

Comment: Up my answer, and check solved ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'filter_text'
```

with

```
Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\TextFilterType::class
```

Replace

```
'filter_boolean'
```

with

```
Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\BooleanFilterType::class
```

Replace

```
'filter_date'
```

with

```
Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\DateFilterType::class
```

Replace

```
'filter_number'
```

with

```
Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\NumberFilterType::class
```